# What is the best way to compare a percentage of data or entire dataset from two databases?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, comparison

The Scenario:

I have two remote databases (source and destination) that I expect to be similar. I want to verify this is true or find out what is missing in the destination database -- Not necessarily concerned about the converse.

I'm using Java 1.8 and OJDBC6 driver to connect to two databases both using Oracle 11g. I'm told using ResultSet rs.next() with Java on an Oracle 11g db is expensive and I'm not sure if there's a better way to compare databases -- I'm open to using a tool or some kind of flat file method if this exists.

The Data:

There are over 300 tables with varying numbers of columns; some tables have primary keys some tables do not.

I believe figuring out which tables have primary keys and which do not was my first step which I perform in SQL:

```
---TABLES WITH PRIMARY KEY
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE OWNER = 'PLTTUX_ADMIN'
AND (CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P')
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

.

```
---TABLES WITHOUT PRIMARY KEY
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM ALL_TABLES
WHERE OWNER = 'PLTTUX_ADMIN'
    MINUS
      SELECT TABLE_NAME
      FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
      WHERE OWNER = 'PLTTUX_ADMIN'
      AND (CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P')
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

I believe sorting these tables properly first was the right approach before comparing. For the tables with primary keys I can simply order by primary key but for the other tables without primary keys I needed a list of all the columns to order by. I found this to be helpful:

```
SELECT listagg(COLUMN_NAME,', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) 
    CSV
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NAME_OF_TABLE';
```

Then I can use that comma separated list:

```
SELECT *
FROM NAME_OF_TABLE
ORDER BY
    (SELECT listagg(COLUMN_NAME,', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) 
        CSV
    FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NAME_OF_TABLE');
```

My Comparison:

Normally, I would take both databases and get a ResultSet for each database using the same SQL commands and proceed with a while loop where rs1.next() and rs2.next() are true.

I can write code to limit my SQL to some number of rows for percent comparison by adding "WHERE ROWNUM <= number_of_rows_returned"

This is where the root of my not-so-short question is: Am I doing all of this in an obvious sub-optimal way? Is there a better way? Is there a tool I should have heard of? Please help me out :) I hope I've shared enough to get some ideas...

Comment: Why do you want to do it in Java? I'd expect there to be some Oracle Kung-Fu to do this directly in the database.

Comment: Have a look at DBMS_COMPARISON, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_comparison.htm#CHDHEFFJ. Jeffrey M. Hunter offers his script to compare schemas, here: http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_scripts/Database_Administration/dba_compare_schemas.sql

Comment: Are these database on the same network? Database links could make this into very quick work.

Comment: I guess "deployment suite for oracle" or "Toad" can do that for you ...

Comment: Maybe it would suffice to select a checksum per table and compare these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps,

1.) Create a database link in the source database to connect that will connect to the destination database.

2.) Use the MINUS set operator to compare data of two tables. Sample below query,

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT *
  FROM table1@dblink;

SELECT *
  FROM table1@dblink
MINUS
SELECT *
  FROM table1;
```

if some rows returned, then there is a difference.